# How many bits(maximum number of bits) can be embedded in a pixel?

Tags: image, image-processing, pixel, steganography, data-hiding

I have an gray scale image of sixe 512x512. Thus, each pixel contains 8 bits. Can I embed a total of 8 bits into the pixels I wish to embed data in? Is this possible? (I require the image only for embedding data). In case I want to embed data in 10,000 pixels out of the total 512*512 pixels, can I then in total embed 80,000 bits of data or 10kB of data?

Comment: I don't know what you are really doing, but sure, you can store 8 bits in each pixel. But that's not much data-hiding then probably.

Comment: You can embed 256KiB of data in a 512x512x8 image. But you cant really embed data within an image without changing what the image looks like What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Explain this : _"Can I embed a total of 8 bits into the pixels I wish to embed data in?"_ ... Do you have an 8-bit or 24-bit grayscale image (eg: 8 bits per R-G-B channel)?

Comment: Yes I know that the image would change visually. I would not be embeding data in all the pixels but a set of selected pixels! Thank you @NickA

Comment: @VC.One a 24bit greyscale image essentially is an 8bit one as all 3 bytes per pixel in the 24bit one have to be the same, otherwise it wouldn't be greyscale

Comment: @NickA true point. I just woke up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard grayscale image with 256 levels for each pixel requires 8 bits per pixel. This is because 8 bits are required to encode 256 different levels. If you have an image with dimensions 512 x 512 then the total number of pixels in the entire image is 262,144 pixels. So, the entire image contains 8 bits * 262,144 = 2,097,152 bits worth of information.

If you were to take a subset of these pixels and encode 8 bits of "different" information, note that the resulting image would likely change in appearance. The 8 bits of information at each pixel coordinate previously encoded the pixel intensity (from 0 to 255). If you are replacing this value with some other value then the intensity will be different and the overall image will appear different.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By any chance do you know what was highest payload of data(in kilobytes) embedded while having a reasonable PSNR value in an image for reversible data hiding?

Comment: That depends on what you consider a "reasonable" peak signal-to-noise ratio. If you fix the PSNR then you could set a maximum bound on the amount of noise you may introduce in the data hiding process. Also keep in mind that there are reversible data hiding methods which don't aim to maximize PSNR (e.g. see https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-19321-2_22)

Comment: @ayovat12 For pixel lsb embedding, as described here, you'd be hard pressed to call the PSNR *reasonable* if you're embedding more than 4 bits per pixel, depending on what information you're embedding and how "busy" the cover image is.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that! But will not alter the visual quality of the image then?

Comment: @ayovat12 The method described in that publication alleges that: "the experimental results have shown that the better effect of contrast enhancement can be achieved than the previous works" and that "In addition to reversibility, the evaluation results show that the visual quality of test images has been preserved after data hiding, even better than three specific MATLAB functions."

Comment: @Reti43 I used "reasonable" as I read that a higher PSNR would give better visual quality. In my case I haven't tried out embedding the pixels yet. So I wanted to know in case I embed 8 bits in about 10,000 pixels out of the 262,144 pixles then can I have an idea will the PSNR be high/low?

Comment: @rudolph1024 you have any idea on my previous comment on the PSNR value being high/low? Thanks!

Comment: Are you replacing the entirety of the 8 bits in each pixel for 10,000 pixels, or are you doing something like replacing 4 bits in each pixel for a total of 20,000 pixels?

Comment: @ayovat12 Writing 8 bits per pixel will completely overwrite it, so you will end up with 10k pixels looking like random noise. That's ~4% of the total image, so yes, that will be perceptible. You are better off spreading that information in more pixels, effectively using a lower bit-per-pixel embedding rate.

Comment: @rudolph1024 in the worst case so as to embed maximum data I would embed 8 bits entirely for all 10,000 pixels!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to embed 10KiB of data in a 512x512 image, where the bit depth is 8 bits, I'd recommend just storing 1 bit of data in every second pixel by changing the LSB of each.

Changing just 1 bit of data from every other pixel allows you to store (512*512*1)/2 bits of data, or 16KiB of data. This way you can store all of the data that you need to while only changing the image in a very limited way.

As an example, here's an image with varying amounts of white-noise embedded within it (by embedding `n` bytes per pixel), you can see how much noise(data) is embedded in the table below:

[image: Images]

```
X | Y | bits used | data(KiB)
0 | 0 | 0         | 0
1 | 0 | 1         | 32
0 | 1 | 2         | 64
1 | 1 | 3         | 96
0 | 2 | 4         | 128
1 | 2 | 5         | 160
0 | 3 | 6         | 192
1 | 3 | 7         | 224
_ | _ | 8         | 256 (image omitted as just white noise)
```

As can be seen, embedding up to 64KiB of data into a 512x512x8 image is perfectly reasonable expecting little noticeable change in the image by editing the 2 LSB of each pixel, so that a pixel is encoded as:

```
XXXX XXYY
```

Where `X` came from the original image, and `Y` is 2 bits of the stored data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I actually am using another method(in which it is not possible to embed in every alternate pixel) where I would be using only a subset of the total pixels! By any chance do you know what was highest payload of data(in kilobytes) embedded while having a reasonable PSNR value in an image for reversible data hiding?